# Tranferring huge data through NFC reader/writer to NFC enabled android phone

Tags: android, nfc, nfc-p2p, open-nfc, lib-nfc

As far as I know, what android did with NFC enabled transferring is that, when both phone recognized each other through NFC, they called up wifi in p2p/ad-hoc mode to do the transfer of music, pictures and etc. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

So I'm thinking whether it is possible to transfer data(MUSIC, JPEG) from an NFC usb reader/writer that hooked up to a computer with an android phone without wifi functionality as most NFC usb reader/writer doesn't include wifi functionality ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The sender is the one that can choose to ask to handover to another technology to complete the transfer (Bluetooth, WiFi-direct). So if your reader is the one sending the content, this should work. I wouldn't recommend it though, as the transfer could take some serious time!

Answer (score 0):

NFC has relatively low data transfer rate, as mentioned, for example, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14717391/371804. So while theoretically this should be possible, practically it would be too slow for transferring any significant amount of data.