# How to change ISO 14443 bit rate via the NFC API?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

As NFC/ISO 14443 support various communication speeds from 106kbps to at least 424 (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14717338/897968)), I am wondering how to switch between these bit rates through the Android API in order to shorten the time it takes to read out the entire memory of ISO 14443A tags.

I looked at the Android [NFC Basics](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html) and [Advanced NFC](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html) documentation as well as various tag technology pages (some of which IMHO should theoretically support some of the higher speeds), but I couldn't find any hints of changing the bit rates.

I also had a look at some tag datasheets and many of them support the ISO14443-4 mechanisms to change the bit rate through the ATS response and PPS command, which I suppose could be manually used through the generic [`transceive(byte[] data)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcA.html#transceive(byte[])) method, but I don't think that would actually change the bit rate of the Android device's NFC chipset... in which case I'd lose the connection to the tag when it switches to a higher speed than the default 106kbps I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISO14443 supports from 106 to 848 using PPS command defined in ISO14443-4,
but NFC (using 14443 protocol) defines only 106kb/s and PPS procedure is out of the scope (PPS command is not described in NFC Forum Digital spec).

The definition that NFC supports from 106kb/s to 424 is because:

- ISO14443 part supports 106kb/s
- Felica part supports 212kb/s and 424kb/s

Therefore I think it is not possible to change the bit rate using Android API.

### EDIT 1:

Incorporating additional information from the comments below:

- The protocol to manage the NFC controller is the [NFC Controller Interface (NCI)](https://www.cardsys.dk/download/NFC_Docs/NFC%20Controller%20Interface%20(NCI)%20Technical%20Specification.pdf) which is followed by the modern NFC Controllers.
- The latest Android Smartphones mostly use the NFC controller chip NXP PN547 (with [NXP PN7120](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PN7120.pdf)).  While the NCI protocol does not "officially" support the use of higher bit rates in technology NFC-A & NFCB, the [PN7150 User Manual](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10936.pdf) indicates that

  > the PN7120 MAY send the PPS command if PI_BIT_RATE was set by the DH to an allowed value higher than 0x00.
- [Android source code defines PI_BIT_RATE = 0x21](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libnfc-nci/+/master/src/hal/include/nci_defs.h), therefore theoretically the NFC Controller could send a PPS up to 212 kbit/s (defined in NCI specification) but this is up to the NFC Controller and cannot be changed by Android API for sure.
- The Android source tree under [platform/system/nfc/halimpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/nfc/+/master/halimpl) includes the HAL implementations for [NXP's PN54x family](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/nfc/+/master/halimpl/pn54x/) and [Broadcom's BCM2079x family](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/nfc/+/master/halimpl/bcm2079x) of controllers (which was apparently [used in Nexus 4 and Nexus 10 devices](https://www.nfcworld.com/2012/11/14/321136/google-picks-broadcom-for-nfc-in-nexus-4-and-nexus-10/)).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have access to version 1.0 of the NFC Digital Protocol which says under the RATS Response of the Type 4A Tag Platform that support for higher bit rates can be indicated by the tag in response to a RATS Command with FSDI set to Fh. It also notes that "Higher bit rates will be specified in next versions of this specification". Unfortunately I don't have access to the current version 2.0 to confirm, but it sounds promising... of course only if Android will provide an API to actually allow changing of the bit rate.

Comment: I haven't got access to "NFC Digital Protocol v2.0" neither. However, I investigated the low level implementation for NFC protocol in Android Source code. At the end the latest Android Smartphones mostly use the NXP PN547 (with NXP PN7120). In its (public) user manual indicates: [NCI] (protocol to manage the NFC controller) does not “officially” support the use of higher bit rates in technology NFC-A & NFCB, however it also indicates that " the PN7120 MAY send the PPS command if
PI_BIT_RATE was set by the DH to an allowed value higher than 0x00".

Comment: Android source code defines in it source code PI_BIT_RATE = 0x21, therefore theorically the NFC Controller could send a PPS up to 212 kbit/s (defined in NCI specification) but this is up to the NFC Controller and cannot be changed by Android API for sure

Comment: Thanks for these detailed updates. Could you provide pointers to these *low level implementation for NFC protocol in the Android source code* you mentioned? I had a quick look but didn't go lower than [BasicTagTechnology](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/nfc/tech/BasicTagTechnology.java#BasicTagTechnology) in the AOSP code... then I'll be happy to accept your answer.

Comment: You could have a look to [HCI](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102600_102699/102622/13.00.00_60/ts_102622v130000p.pdf) also check the NFC Forum standard called (NCI)[https://www.cardsys.dk/download/NFC_Docs/NFC%20Controller%20Interface%20(NCI)%20Technical%20Specification.pdf] which is followed by the modern NFC Controllers, as NFC Forum specs are not public and I cannot provide the latest publications you could also check the datasheet of [PN7120](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/UM10819.pdf) which is the NFC Controller that most smarphones brings today

Comment: [NCI](https://www.cardsys.dk/download/NFC_Docs/NFC%20Controller%20Interface%20(NCI)%20Technical%20Specification.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll look at them later. Where did you find related Android source code you mentioned in [your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877073/how-to-change-iso-14443-bit-rate-via-the-nfc-api#comment76782219_44886803)?

Comment: In the HAL implementation of NFC layer for PN54x of NXP: \\(...)\system\nfc\halimpl\pn54x\

Comment: Accepted your answer and extended it with the information I could extract from your comments.